# Class Set With Elements on Heap in A Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, set, heap-memory

How can one create a `Set` object that stores its elements on the heap in a dynamic array of `int` values? In particular, how does one create an empty set with these specifications?

---

```
//  Morally Right (M) 2014 1-ling. All morals preserved.

class Set 
{

public:

    Set();
    Set( int element );
    Set(const Set& s );
    ~Set();

    bool contains( unsigned int element );
    unsigned int getSize();

    int operator[]( unsigned int index ) const;
    Set& operator=( const Set s );
    Set operator+=( const Set s ) const;
    Set operator-=( const Set s ) const;
    Set operator*=( const Set s ) const;

    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& o , const Set& s );
    friend istream& operator>>( istream& i , const Set& s );

private:

    int *array = new int[size]; // IS THIS THE PATH TO SUCCESS?
    int* elements();
    unsigned int size();
    void copy( const Set& s );
    void resize( unsigned int new_size );

};
```

Comment: Is `Set` a user-defined class or a name for some kind of container?

Comment: If you go to UCLA, please don't copy this code. Do it yourself. I don't want the professor thinking I ripped this off if you turn in your work with the exact same structure.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you have now?

Comment: Am I looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/c-how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers

Comment: @0x499602D2, well, I don't know how to create a dynamic array of `int` values.

Comment: But the question you linked shows exactly how to do that. Using a `new` keyword.

Comment: Yes. Dynamic means that the size can be provided at runtime. However the main part of this assignment is that you will need to create, copy and delete dynamic arrays in each of the functions you mentioned. Also  you shouldn't do it in your header file, but in your implementation file, generally.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would recommend that you use [`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), but since your assignment tells you to use raw C-style arrays, I will have to reiterate my answer thusly:

If you're holding a resource (such as dynamic memory) you will have to implement the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization%E2%80%8E) idiom so that the resource is deallocated when encapsulating structure goes out of scope. For this you will need a destructor so that you can appropriately call `delete`/`delete[]`. Doing otherwise causes a memory leak if you're using dynamic memory and it's not deallocated.

But to allocate the resource, you will need a constructor that calls `new`/`new[]`. And to implement copying, you will need a copy-constructor that copies the resource from the other object to your object.

---

Now that I've laid out the instructions, you can start. Note that you already have the appropriate default-constructor, copy-constructor, and destructor to perform the aforementioned activities. To create a pointer to the memory, you can simply use `int* element` and assign it to memory.

[**For more information, see this post.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: If he's allowed to used STL why not just use std::set?

Comment: I can't. Instructions: Your supervisor wanted you to make some design changes to your Set class. The biggest change is make your `Set` objects store their elements not in a vector
of `int` values, but on the heap in a dynamic array of `int` values. As a consequence, you will need to redefine the copy constructor, assignment operator `=`, and destructor in order to prevent shallow copies and memory leaks.

Comment: I just love how the professor is inculcating the minds of tomorrow with the expectation that everyone will be working under a "supervisor."

Comment: @user3250884 Give me a few while I update my answer.

Comment: saying that C-style arrays are bad practice is a bit harsh. there are plenty of valid use cases.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Sure I know, but it's best to discourage use of explicit `new` in favor of standard containers.

Comment: What does it mean to have an empty set in this instance?

Comment: @user3250884 An empty set means that in the default-constructor you initialize `element` to `nullptr` in the member-initializer list.

Comment: For the `Set( int element )` constructor I set `size=1`, correct?

Comment: @user3250884 I'm assuming `int element` is the value you want to add to the array, right? If so, then yes, the size should be equal to one.

Comment: `Set::Set( int element ) { size = 1; array[0] = { element }; }`

Comment: @0x499602D2, should elements = element?

Comment: @user3250884 [let us continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46386/discussion-between-0x499602d2-and-user3250884)

Comment: I just realized I made a mistake. The constructor that takes an integer should be the size of the array. Meaning `S::S(int elements) : array(new int[elements]), size(elements) {}`. Sorry!