# C++ create array with dynamic size

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

How can I create a array with dinamic size like this:

```
int sentLen = sentences.size();

double a[sentLen][sentLen];

for (int i = 0; i < sentLen; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sentLen; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = somefunction(i, j);
    }
}
```

My research led me to `malloc` which isn't recommended or other too complicated methods. After I realised that size must be constant, I tried using `unordered_map`, and I have tried the following:

```
std::unordered_map <int, int, double> a;


for (int i = 0; i < sentLen; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sentLen; j++)
    {
        a.insert({ i, j, somefunc(i, j) });
    }
}
```

but still unsuccessful.

Comment: It depends on what you mean "dynamic size". Also there is nothing wrong with your first code block.

Comment: @Daniel I'm getting `Expressions must have a constant value` with the first code.

Comment: What compiler and version are you using? Older compilers do not support variable length arrays. If your compiler doesn't support it, minimal research is required to [find the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to use arrays.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> a{
   sentLen, std::vector<double>{ sentLen, 0.0 } };

for (int i = 0; i < sentLen; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sentLen; ++j)
    {
        a[i][j] = somefunc(i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Tho seems there is syntax error, because I got it running like `std::vector<std::vector<double>> a(sentLen, std::vector<double>(sentLen, 0.0));`

Comment: Based on his first example, I don't believe the OP really needs any of the functionality of a vector, other than being able to declare it of variable length. He should use array pointers and `new` the memory himself. Using a vector of vectors is overkill.

Comment: @Deepsy Put a space between the end brackets `> >`.

Comment: Using the `new` operator is generally a bad idea.

Comment: The `{}` initialization is a C++11 feature.  Your post looked like you were attempting to use it.  If you use g++ or clang++, try the `-std=c++11` switch.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because you can't use variables as static array sizes. They must be known at compile time. You have to allocate dynamically or use a vector instead.