# variable-sized array type ‘int [size]’ is not a valid template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am getting following error in c++ program :

> variable-sized array type ‘int [size]’ is not a valid template
>   argument

for following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void func (T& Array)
{
    cout << "Hi";
}

int main ()
{
    int size = 100;
    int arr [100];
    int arr1 [size];
    func (arr);   // compiled
    func (arr1);  // gives error
}
```

Please Help me to resolve this. I want to take size of array from some variable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: C++ doesn't actually have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), though some compilers add it as an extension to the language.

Comment: What do you do with your `Array` in your template function `func(T& Array)`? You don't do anything with it. To fix your problem, you may use dynamic allocation but template is not a solution to it.

Comment: As for your problem, remember that templates are pure compile-time features. Variable-length arrays are created at runtime.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude here only solution is hard coding?

Comment: This might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers

Comment: We can't really tell you a solution, because we don't know the *actual* problem you want to solve with this. You ask us to help you fix a solution to an (for us) unknown problem, and this is called [*the XY problem*](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `std::vector<int>   arr1(size);` will likely work.

Comment: Please clarify what your problem is, the program shown will not compile, ever. Taking sizes of variable-length arrays are possible as a runtime value, but this doesn't fix your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
int size = 100;
```

with

```
const int size = 100;
```

In this way, the compiler knows that `size` will not change and can properly allocate space for the static array `arr1`

Comment: That's not the problem. VLAs can exist because the compiler knows how to "properly" deal with it.

Comment: @PasserBy Not sure what you mean, because the suggested change will make the program legal official C++, cause the array bound to be known at compile time, and make it possible to use the array type as a deduced template argument.

Comment: @aschepler The explanation says space cannot be allocated due to it being a runtime value, which is not true. Of course it can, otherwise such extensions wouldn't be possible. The badness is due to it not being standard and wrecks the type system.

Comment: @PasserBy: you are right, but it's extremely unsafe to use a variable to define the size of an array. Clever compiler will generate a warning i think. What happens if `arr1`, defined as `int`, is then modified to a greater value and than you cicle over the `arr1` elements using `size` as bound? Obviously a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: `constexpr` could also be used

Answer (score -2):

In C++ you can't define array's size using variable. 
I suggest you to replace this array with **vector** or define a **preprocessor macro** that will hold size for your array.

Comment: _preprocessor macro_ no, it's C++, never use macros where you can use integer constants.