# Inconsistency with arrays

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int grade(char [][5], int);

int main()
{
    int tests, i,j;
    cout << "How many tests?"; cin >> tests;
    char answers[tests][5];
    cout << "What were the answers for all the tests (T/F)?";
    for (i=0;i<tests;i++)
        for (j=0;j<5;j++) cin >> answers[i][j];;
    int g[tests] = {grade(answers, tests)};

    for (i=1;i<=tests;i++)
    {
        cout << "\n   Test " << i << ": ";
        cout << g[i-1] << " out of 25";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

int grade(char ans[][5], int test)
{
    int k, l;
    int gr[test]={0};
    char sheet[5] = {'T', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'T'}; cout << sheet[1];
    for (k=0;k<test;k++)
            for (l=0;l<5;l++)
                    if (ans[k][l]==sheet[l]) gr[k]+= 5;;;

    return *gr;
}
```

I can't figure out why my program is so inconsistent. If I input T T F F T for the first test, everything turns out fine, but if I have any "wrong answers" for the first test, the values of my g array seem to always be 0.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Too complicated. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: what's with multiple semicolons?

Comment: `int gr[test]={0};` is not valid standard C++

Comment: “Use `std::vector`” is not a useful comment; it does not solve the problem(s), instead seeking to change OP’s structure without explaining what benefit it has/problem it obviates. Perhaps pointing out that `grade()` could use to take a single-dimension (sub)array to simplify instead...

Comment: Your function returns a single int . I guess you imagine to return the entire `gr` but you do not

Comment: @Dúthomhas: *"Use std::vector” is not a useful comment;"* - Yes, it is. Even if it does not solve the problem directly, it makes the code shorter, more readable and more debuggable, contributing to a solution in the long run. So let me reiterate it: **Use `std::vector`.**

Comment: I've no idea what std::vector does, so I cannot use this advice.

M M
So are you saying that when I return the gr array, it only sends one value?

Comment: @RobertPaulson: `std::vector` is practically the default container of C++. What book are you using that does not teach you how to use the default container of the language?! See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @ChristianHackl At this point I doubt this is C++ related question at all

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem. The return value of the function returns a single number, and then assigns that single number to all values of the array. So, whatever the first test's grade was, all grades read the same.

The {} after an array sets the initial values for the array, and only having one value in that makes that value be assigned to all parts of the array.

My compiler doesn't like your syntax of `int g[tests]`, as it expects `tests` to be a constant, so I had to convert those dynamic array size declarations. The following code worked as expected for me on Visual Studio 2017. Try this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* grade(char** ans, int test);

int main()
{
    int tests, i, j;
    cout << "How many tests?"; cin >> tests;

    char** answers = new char*[tests];
    for (int i=0;i<tests;i++)
        answers[i] = new char[5];

    cout << "What were the answers for all the tests (T/F)?";
    for (i = 0; i<tests; i++)
        for (j = 0; j<5; j++) cin >> answers[i][j];

    int* g = grade(answers, tests);

    for (i = 1; i <= tests; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n   Test " << i << ": ";
        cout << g[i - 1] << " out of 25";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++)
        delete[] answers[i];
    delete[] answers;
    delete[] g;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

int* grade(char** ans, int test)
{
    int k, l;
    int* gr = new int [test] {0};
    char sheet[5] = { 'T', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'T' }; 
    cout << sheet[1];
    for (k = 0; k<test; k++)
        for (l = 0; l<5; l++)
            if (ans[k][l] == sheet[l]) gr[k] += 5;;;

    return gr;
}
```

Comment: I'm using codeblocks, if that helps anyhow.
I'm confused at what you did.

        for (i=0;i<tests;i++)
            delete[] answers[i];
        delete[] answers;
        delete[] g;
    
What does this do after I already cout my values?
When I get rid of * for return gr, my values get wonky.
I understood what you said the problem was and it makes sense looking at the code, but I still have no idea how you fixed it in yours. Could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @RobertPaulson When I dynamically allocate the arrays, they must be deallocated manually, done by delete[] ing them. I do a for loop since I want to delete all the arrays within an array. The operating system would also do this automatically if you wanted to ignore it, but that would be bad coding practice, and could lead to a memory leak.

Comment: @RobertPaulson I return the int* in the function since I have already created the array in the function, then I pass the location to `int* g`, and use that in the output of the program. I then `delete[]` that since it won't delete automatically. More about delete[] and dynamic arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers

Comment: @RobertPaulson Did this answer your question?

Comment: When I use int* for the function protocol, I can't use return*, and then my program outputs super high numbers for the g[tests] values. =(

Comment: @RobertPaulson I'm sorry but I don't understand what you just said. Can you elaborate with some code perhaps?

Comment: int grade(char [][5], int);
when I use int* instead of int here, when I call my function, and at the bottom where I define my function, I can't use return* gr and my "Test # out of 25" statements shoot up to 49235.

Comment: @RobertPaulson I still don't entirely understand what you are saying, so I'll just try to hit a few points and see if I get it... First of all, you don't do `return* gr`, just `return gr`. `return* gr` is actually `return *gr`, which just returns a single integer instead of the array. Also, make sure the declaration, `int* grade(char** ans, int test);` matches with the definition `int* grade(char** ans, int test)
{ ...`. Next, make sure you are using the code I supplied; I gave you a working solution. Your `int grade(char [][5], int); ` is not going to work with the method I supplied.

Comment: If you are having further issues, please post the code you are using on something and give me the link to it.

Comment: I literally copy and pasted your program and it worked haha. I've got to go to class now, but I'll elaborate my question again. I still don't get how my program was problematic after I edited it with your help. Thank you so much!