# int *tab1[5]; but dynamically

Tags: c++

I need a help with c++.

```
int *tab1[5];
int tab2[] = {3, 4, 5};
tab1[0] = tab2;
```

It works but I want to have a variable instead of 5 in first line.
Any ideas? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Always `std::vector`.

Comment: arrays should ALWAYS be compile time constants (even if your compiler has an extension to allow you to use variables).  You can get away with `constexpr unsigned int arraySize=5` but that's not a variable in the way I think you want it to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a dynamic array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you found the "wrong" answer I'll show you the "correct":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "How many lines do you want? ";
    unsigned lines;
    if (!(std::cin >> lines))
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tab(lines);

    if (lines > 0)
    {
        tab[0] = { 3, 4, 5 };
    }
}
```

Comment: Ew, vectors of vectors

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer,

```
int n = 5;
int **tab1 = new int*[n];
int tab2[] = {3, 4, 5};
tab1[0] = tab2;
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Careful: that assignment doesn't do what you [probably] think it does.