# Write the required code to create a dynamic one dimensional integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, dimensional

I'm not sure how to answer this question or what it ask exactly for.

> Q:Write the required code to create a dynamic one dimensional integer
>   array.

So does it ask just to make dynamic 1D array like this:

```
new int [5] 
or 
new int [size]
```

or it ask for another answer like this one:

```
int size = 5;

int *ptr;

ptr = new int[size];
```

Thank you.

Comment: From where did you get the question? A person? Then ask that person instead. If it's a book, then perhaps you need to check the context.

Comment: Also, for future reference, unless this question is about pointers, whenever you think "dynamic array" your next thought should *always* be `std::vector`.

Comment: I think it all depends on whether dynamic refers to the array itself, or the allocation of the array.

Comment: It's from old C++ exam.

Comment: Your first answer doesn't assign the array to any integer, so it's a bit less than optimal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers Mayhap this is the answer you're looking for? It details how to properly create a dynamically-allocated array of integers.

Comment: IMO the only one that is wrong is `new int [size];` because it doesn't declare `size` and so the code is incomplete. Otherwise they all answer the question.

Comment: This isn't really answerable...

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

A vector is what you want.

```
#include <vector>
// some stuff
std::vector<int> A(size);
```