# Using local variable outside its scope

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

```
while(t!=0)
{
    for(j=1;j <=3;j++)
    {
       cin>>size;
       int arrj[size];

       for(i=0;i<3;i++)
       {
           cin>>arrj [i];
       }
    }
}
```

How do I use `arrj[]` outside the while `loop` as the array is a local variable to while loop?

Comment: In regards to your question, you can't. The scope of the array is only inside the first `for` loop. Then another point, C++ doesn't actually have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). If you need it then use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I use arrj[] outside the `while` loop **as the array is a local**
>   **variable** to while loop?

You have the answer in your question itself. You **can not** have the `arrj` out side the first `for` loop as it will be deleted from the stack as it go out of from this scope.

In order to use the `arrj[]`, you need it to be declared before the `while` loop:

```
   int t = 2, size = 10;
   int arrj[size];   // declare before

   while(t!=0)  // this should be t--, otherwise your while loop will not end
   {
      /* code */
   }
```

However, as it look like to have array of integers as per user choise, I recommend you to use [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), by which you can achieve what you want to have.

```
   int t = 1, size;
   std::vector<int> arrj; // declare here

   while(t--)
   {
      for(int j=1;j <=3;j++)
      {
         std::cin>> size;
         // resize the vector size as per user choise
         arrj.resize(size);
         // now you can fill the vector using a range based for loop
         for(int& elements: arrj)  std::cin >> elements;

         // or simply
         /*while(size--) 
         {
            int elements; std::cin >> elements;
            arrj.emplace_back(elements)
         }*/
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a vector or array declared outside the loop to hold the value.
with Vector you can push_back
or with array you can do  [dynamic allocation on heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers)