# How to implement local variables that can be used in other places with the same conditions in C++

Tags: c++

How to get the following code to work?

```
int main(){
    bool flag = true;

    if(flag){
        // note that I donot want to define variable globally.
        int a = 5;
    }

    if(flag){
        // but I still want to use this local variable within the same condition.
        a++;
    }
}
```

Note that I don't want to define this variable globally or use a static variable.
I'm curious if there is a way for c++ to make local variables available in all regions with the same conditions?

Comment: No, that's the whole point of being local / scoped.

Comment: Change the variable's scope to be the scope you want.

Comment: Make a function flag() that returns the correct value?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a variable that's accessible in two different functions but that is not global. Have you considered making a class including both functions and a private variable accessible to both functions? (Of course in C++, "functions" in a class are normally referred to as "methods".)

Comment: Is [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) what you're looking for?

Comment: @DavidYockey • in C++, functions in a class are normally referred to as **member functions**.  In other OO languages, and in OOP in general, they are referred to as **methods**.  (But I'm with you, and I call them *methods* as well.)

Comment: @Eljay Ah, that's true. Guess I'm too used to thinking in OOP terms.

Comment: If you want to use a local variable in a different scope (such as a different function) pass a reference to it to the function

Comment: Define `int a{};` locally in **main**, rather than locally within a nested scope within **main**.

Comment: Related/dupe: [Using local variable outside its scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712236/)

Answer (score 3):

What you ask for literally is a local variable that is not a local variable. Thats not possible.

On the other hand, you basically want data + code, thats a class. If you wrap it in a class your function can look like this:

```
int main(){   
    Foo f;
    f.doSomething();
}
```

And the class can be this

```
struct Foo {
   bool flag = false;
   int a = 0;
   void doSomething() {
      if (flag) ++a;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're *directly* asking for isn't possible.  You'll have to declare *something* up front.  If it's about *avoiding construction* of objects until you have some relevant detail, you could use `std::optional`

```
int main()
{
    std::optional<int> a;

    if(flag)
    {
       a = 10;
    }

    if(a)
    {
        *a++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the variable's scope to be the scope you want it to be.

```
int main(){
    bool flag = true;

    // declare it in this scope if you want it to persist
    // thru this scope
    int a;

    if(flag){
        a = 5;
    }

    if(flag){
        a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I did not make it clear, what I want is to define in local, instead of define in global, and I still want to use the local variable in another place.

Comment: @jingruiyu `a` is defined directly within the function without any storage specifiers, so it's a local variable.

Comment: @jingruiyu a variable local to a scope is, well, local to the scope where it is declared, period. What you're asking for for doesn't make much sense. What is your use case? Why is the method suggested in the answer a problem?

Comment: Can you say more about _why_ you want to do it the way you write in your original question, and why my answer doesn't get you what you want? This feels like an XY problem. What do you think you gain by not declaring the variable in the wider scope?

Answer (score 1):

No.

According to [section 6.4.3, basic.scope.block](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.block):

> 1 Each
>
> - (1.1) selection or iteration statement ([[stmt.select]](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.select), [stmt.iter]),
> - [...]
> - (1.4) compound statement ([stmt.block]) that is not the compound-statement of a handler
>
> introduces a block scope that includes that statement or handler.
>
> A variable that belongs to a block scope is a block variable.

According to [section 6.7.5.4, basic.stc.auto, clause 1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#stc.auto-1):

> Variables that belong to a block or parameter scope and are not explicitly declared static, thread_­local, or extern have automatic storage duration. The storage for these entities lasts until the block in which they are created exits.