# User inputs array size(N). Numbers from 0 until N fill the array

Tags: c++

It's supposed to be N={0,1,2...N}
N is entered by the user.
If N is 6 then N={0,1...5}
The numbers from 0 to N should fill the array.
We haven't studied vectors yet so that's not an option.

Comment: Use `std::cin` to read `N`, then use `new[]` to allocate an array of `N` elements, then use a loop from `0` to `N-1` inclusive to fill the array (as I assume you haven't studied standard library algorithms either, like `std::fill()`, `std::generate_n()`, etc). Have you tried that yet? Dynamic arrays should be covered by any decent C++ tutorial/book.

Comment: Then you will have to use a dynamic array, this will help you [How to create a dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029897/7631183)

Comment: Don't expect us to do your homework. What have you tried so far? Show us your code please.

Comment: I tried a few different ones but nothing worked. I tried searching what to use but everything got confusing. Most of the example codes contain elements we haven't studied

Comment: Do the "elements" you *have* studied include integral types, reading input, dynamic allocation/deallocation using operators `new` and `delete`, and loops?   If so, you have studied all the necessary ingredients to solve your homework problem on your own.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, allocate in memory an array of size n+1

```
int *arr= new int[n+1];
```

Iterate over this array, and assign the corresponding values

```
for(int i=0; i<n+1; ++i)
  arr[i] = i;
```

Comment: It is not too helpful just to provide the code without any explanation. OP seems to be a beginner, risk is that she/he will just copy/paste the code without learning anything...

Comment: Most coding conventions mandate variables being named in camel case, starting with small letter. `N` would violate this convention, you should prefer `n` instead.