# how to do automatic array detection?

Tags: c++

I sometimes get confused in these numbers with an array and can’t count because the beginning is from scratch and not from one.
And so that I do not get confused, I have to remove the numbers with the size of the `arr[4][4].`

I want to find a way for this to work automatically, more precisely, it automatically determines the numbers.

I'm really confused
for me `arr[4][4]`. it should be `arr[3][3].`
because the counter starts at zero `0,1,2,3`

```
int arr[][] // <--
    {
        { 0,0,0,1 },
        { 1,0,0,0 },
        { 0,2,0,4 },
        { 1,1,0,1 }
    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a dynamic array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers)

Comment: @ivanjermakov: no dynamic in the question. It is about static ones :-)

Comment: Can you please edit your question post and try to explain what your question is? I'm not sure it is very clear from what you're describing.

Comment: My understanding is: OP did not want to provide the size parameters for array creation. Op searches a func/helper/something to get an two or multi dimensional array from the given parameters.

Comment: What should be the type if the inner dimension is inconsistent? And would you be fine with making `arr` an `std::array<std::array<...>>`? Also, can you use C++17?

Comment: Arrays in C and C++ (as well as most other languages) start with index 0.  Best to get used to it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe like it with a helper function like that:

```
#include < array >
#include < iostream >

template < typename ... T  >
constexpr auto f( T ... args) 
{   
    return std::array< std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<T...>>, sizeof...(args)> { args...};
}   

int main()
{   
    constexpr auto arr = 
        f(
            f( 0,0,0,1),
            f( 1,0,0,0),
            f( 0,2,0,4),
            f( 1,1,0,1)
         );  

    for ( auto& x: arr ) { 
        for ( auto y: x ) { 
            std::cout << y << " " ;
        }   
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }   

    // or access via []
    std::cout << arr[0][3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[2][3] << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want something simpler and less.
If you can, suggest other options.

Comment: @loli: A functionality which is simpler than a single line? Sorry, I can't :-)