# “ error: incompatible types in assignment of” when trying to resize array of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers

I'm trying to resize this array of pointers to objects. Essentially, I'm attempting to create a new array of pointers to objects, twice the size of the original one, fill the new one with the original one, and then have the original one pointed to the new one.

Seems like everything is working out until I try to assign the new one to the old one.

If I just do the copy, to the new temporary array, it runs. If I try to assign the temporary one to the old one, it gives me an error.

This is what I'm working with:

Working on taking this, which is a data member of a class file:

```
tiger *tigerDen[10];      //Tiger array
```

and expanding it like this:

```
if (tigerIndexTracker + 1 > tigerDenSize)
{
    tigerDenSize = tigerDenSize * 2;
    tiger* temp[tigerDenSize];

    for (int count = 0; count < tigerIndexTracker; count++)
    {
        temp[count] = tigerDen[count];

    } 

    tigerDen = temp;

}
```

Really not sure what needs to be done to make this one work. Would love some help.

Exact error I get (not sure if it's intelligible):

> error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘tiger* [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype >((zoo*)this)->zoo::tigerDenSize) + -1)) + 1)]’ to ‘tiger* [10]’
>     tigerDen = temp;

There's an arrow pointing to the assignment operator.

Edit: tigerDenSize is just an int that's set to 20. tigerIndexTracker is an int set to 10. Essentially, what I'm doing is trying to sense if an object is about to be added to the array that will take it over it's limit, and if so, create a new array that I can move everything to.

Comment: Typo in `ssizetype`

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Is `tigerDenSize` a compile time constant? If not your code relies on non-standard compiler extension (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: why dont you use `std::vector`?

Comment: @drescherjm The `tigerIndexTracker + 1 > tigerDenSize` shows that purpose of this code is to make `tigerDen` bigger. But C++ doesn't work that way. You can't make `tigerDen` bigger.

Comment: `tigerDen = temp;` is not going to work. And `tiger* temp[tigerDenSize];` is a local variable.

Comment: ***I'm trying to resize this array of pointers to objects.*** You can't resize an array in `c++` it is a fixed size at compile time. If you are not permitted to use `std::vector` you will have to dynamically allocate memory.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Sorry, I removed something by accident. Added it back and edited my post. For the record, it still doesn't work. And I wish I could just use a vector, but it's against the assignment.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers/4029919](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers/4029919)

Comment: @drescherjm I understand technically that's true. From what I could find, if you wanted to accomplish that, you'd need to make another array to pour the first one into, which is what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: You most likely need to use new[] and delete[] to create and destroy a dynamic array. Like in my previous comment.

Comment: many problems in your code, unfortunately I am too bad with arrays to write an answer. The only thing I know for sure is that you should have covered dynamic allocations in your lecture, otherwise the task makes no sense

Comment: Tried to switch `tiger* temp[tigerDenSize];` to  `tiger* temp = new tiger[tigerDenSize];` and now I'm ending up with errors coming from my tiger class header file, such as `tiger.hpp:18:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
tiger.hpp:12:7: note: tiger::tiger(const tiger&)
 class tiger: public animal
       ^
tiger.hpp:12:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided` No idea why.

Comment: @Mär  Thank you, but that's the error. It is not the issue.

Comment: @WaresEngineer `tiger* temp[tigerDenSize];` is an array of pointers while `tiger* temp = new tiger[tigerDenSize];` is an array of `tiger`s. I guess the error occurrs because `tiger` has no default constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here is your code:

```
if (tigerIndexTracker + 1 > tigerDenSize)
{
    tigerDenSize = tigerDenSize * 2;
    tiger* temp[tigerDenSize];

    for (int count = 0; count < tigerIndexTracker; count++)
    {
        temp[count] = tigerDen[count];
    } 
    tigerDen = temp;
}
```

What is happening is that you create your new temp array on the stack, copy stuff to it, and then when your if-statement ends, that memory is going to be reused. Yuck!

The proper way to do this:

```
   tiger * temp = new tiger*[tigerDenSize];

   ... copy like you already do

   delete [] tigerDen;  // This frees the original array
   tigerDen = temp;
```

Also, in your header you need to change your pointer:

```
   tiger ** tigerDen = nullptr;
```

Note that tigerDenSize then should be assigned to 0 at the start. Or you can pre-allocate some spaces.

Comment: @JosephLarson Wow, thanks a lot for taking the time to help me! If I could ask you one more thing, if I was doing stuff like this: `cout << "Tiger is age: " << tigerDen[pregnancyCounter]->getAge() << endl;` throughout my code, and I was using tigerDen, would would I need to go through and change everything using tigerDen like that to? I am still learning pointers :(

Comment: The `cout << "Tiger is age: " << tigerDen[pregnancyCounter]->getAge() << endl;` would remain the same.