# Compiler get error message (textc.exe has stopped)

Tags: c++

**C++ Program**
Here is some problem that i faced.After compile it opened  a popup window and give me error message "textc.exe has stopped" then i got black screen.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,n,a[10],b[10]//a[10],b[10];
    cout<<"enput array size: ";
```

1. List item

   ```
   cin>>n;
   cout<<"Enter some number";
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       cin>>a[i];
   }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       b[i]=a[i];
       cout<<"a["<<i<<"]= "<<a[i]<<"\t\t"<<"b["<<i<<"]="<<b[i]<<"\n";
   }
   return 0;
   }
   ```

If i change my code little bit as like a[10],b[10]  instead of a[n],a[n]

then it work perfectly.
what is wrong here.

Comment: you are creating an array with an uninitialized size

Comment: What is a[10] - Array of 10 elements. What is a[n]  - array of n elements. in you do int n, a[n]; What is the value of n? Its unitialized, so can even be a negative value. So what will be a[n] in that case? That mean you need to initialize n before using in a[n]

Comment: i want size of array after input value as
'int a[n];
cin>>n;'
after taking value of n my array size will be a[10] if i input value of n=10

Comment: @Skshivangi try to look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers , or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way to initialize:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int size;
    int *a, *b;

    std::cout << "Enter the size of array: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    a = new int[size]; // dynamic initialization
    b = new int[size]; // of arrays

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        a[i] = b[i] = 0; // initializing to zero

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        std::cin >> a[i]; // taking variable of n elements for a

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i]; // same as a[i], copied
        std::cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << "\t\t" << "b[" << i << "] = " << b[i] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Disclaimer

Array size must be a positive integer and not garbage value and overflowed values are not allowed here too. You can try `std::vector<>` for dynamic array initialization and also it has a capability of expanding and shrinking.