# C++ E0028 expression must have a constant value. array

Tags: c++, arrays

For my code I having an error as stated with arrays and am not sure as to how to fix it I have included some of my code

```
switch (level_of_play) {

case 1:

    size = 4;

    speed_of_play = 6;

    break;
```

There are multiple cases I have just included one. The error then arises

```
string answer_grid[size][size];/** answer array**/

string display_grid[size][size];/**display array**/

srand(time(NULL));
```

I tried to place the string size into the case but that will not work as my program uses display_gride in further parts outside of the cases.
Please help with how I can fix this to allow still multiple choices of array size.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029870/how-to-create-a-dynamic-array-of-integers

Comment: If you are using `string` then you should also know how to use `vector`. This is the solution to your problem.

Comment: `vector<vector<string>> answer_grid(size, vector<string>(size));`

Comment: You are a life saver and thank you! The class I am hardly taught string so didn't even know about vector.